# Pivot table showing wrong values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table in excel. My source value has a country column to show the country of each user

[image]

After converting this into a pivot table, the country value "US" in the source value shows as "r" in the pivot table, rest all the values show as it is.
[image]

I am not able to figure out why it is showing as r for US values? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably overwrite the value in pivot, where you accidentally press r while the cursor is on US in the pivot table. underlying data is still US.

Two ways that I know of to fix this, select the r in pivot and overwrite it to US again, OR
rename all US to USA in your raw data and refresh pivot. Then rename it back to US and refresh pivot.